# How to select distinct year from a datetime column and add the result to a comboBox in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 and SQL Management Studio R2
Although the sql query works fine in sql management studio. Its throws an exception in visual studio. Out of index exception whem i edit to make any other adjustments it throws Out of format exception. Please Help me. The code is as follows:

```
 string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year(tdate) FROM saletransaction ORDER BY Year(tdate) DESC";
 cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);                
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 DateTime dt;
 while (dr.Read())
 {
     if (dr.HasRows == true)
     {
         dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["tdate"].ToString()); //tdate is the name of the column (getting an error at this line. )
         comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.Year.ToString());
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is the format of your datetimes in your database?

Comment: the tdate is already converted to simple Year i.e simple string so the error might be because you are attempting a simple year string to datetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not selecting `tdate` but you select `Year(tdate)`

I would modify the query to this:

```
string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year(tdate) AS tdate_year FROM saletransaction ORDER BY Year(tdate) DESC";
```

and access it with `dr["tdate_year"]`

Comment: i got it. Thank you Wouter Huysentruit.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed to give the column name in sql query

try this

```
string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year(tdate) AS tdate FROM saletransaction ORDER BY Year(tdate) DESC";
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have not given an alias to your `tdate` query. Therefore when you try and reference `tdate`, the column does not exist and Visual Studio throws the error.

Change the query to:

```
 string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year(tdate) AS tdate FROM saletransaction ORDER BY Year(tdate) DESC";
```

Which will return all your results under the column name `tdate`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you Darren Davies.

Comment: @Suvee- can you please stop marking the answer as accepted and then unaccepted.  It has changed 3 times over the last day.